# Rails 4 remove some validation error messages but not all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want my validation message to no matter what error be simply the following:

"example: (415) 944-2099"

I have the following in my model

```
  validates :phonenumber, presence: {is: true, message: " "},
                          format: {with: VALID_PNUM_REGEX, message: "example: (415) 944-2099" },
                          length: {in: 10..15, message: " "}
```

The above code though displays the following (if the field is left blank, therefore not matching any of the requirements):
", example: (415) 944-2099,"

How do I get rid of the commas or simply make my own overall validation message?

Comment: you saying when you submit the form with blank :phonenumber, you get the following error message: `", example: (415) 944-2099,"`. and that you simply want to remove the two commas?

Comment: is it coming from this variable: `VALID_PNUM_REGEX` ?

Comment: What about using the scaffold generated _errors_message? you can customize it. let me know if you'd like to see that

Comment: @WaliAli The commas were actually coming from the fact that I have three separate validators, therefore rails generates three unique error messages--separated by commas. I just wanted to know how to create an overall general error message that would be displayed no matter what the error is. The bottom answer actually solved what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this validator in your model:

```
validate :phone_validator

def phone_validator
  if phonenumber.blank? || !phonenumber.match(VALID_PNUM_REGEX) || !phonenumber.length.in?(10..15)
    self.errors.add(:phonenumber, 'example: (415) 944-2099')
  end
end
```